# How to go on navigation when I click on markers

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, maps

i've this code to mark a point on map, with position, title and snippet but, if I want to go to navigation?

```
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(X,Y))
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Snippet")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

Comment: what you want to do on marker click ? want to go to some another page or anything else .?

Comment: I want to go on Google Maps app and go to that direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use a intent in the in this way:

```
String baseUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%s,%s&daddr=%s,%s"

String uri = String.format(baseUri, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude)

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code will be executed in `onMarkerClick` callback that you will override registring the `setOnMarkerClickListener` on your `GoogleMap` object. Something like:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {      //mMap is a GoogleMap object   
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        if(marker.equals(marker_1)){
            //call the intent here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```